# NodeJS download file with another user rights

Tags: node.js, express, permissions

The user, that runs my node js server doesn't have permissions to download files from some directory with files on server, so if i use express function res.download(filepath, filename); i get an Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat '\MySerevr\Archive\MyFile.doc'.
I have user/password of a user, that have permissison on the directory. So,my question is, is there any way to download files from server using somones credentials?